# datalloader function ,and the iter function is cleared, but the next() function causes errors

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

The datalloader function is used in pytorch, and the iter function is cleared, but the next() function causes errors. If you know the solution or the cause, please help me.

I've changed the batch size.

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224,224),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5))])

train = ImageFolder('/home/minseok/study/dog_cat/train',transform)
valid = ImageFolder('/home/minseok/study/dog_cat/valid',transform)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train,batch_size=256,num_workers=8,shuffle=True)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid,batch_size=2,num_workers=1,shuffle=True)

dataiter = iter(valid_loader)  #It's safe up to here
images, labels = dataiter.next() # error
```

I am sorry for my poor English explanation because it is non-English speaking.

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting? It's not surprising that `iter(valid_loader)` doesn't fail because iterators are lazy and you only perform the actual IO when you call `next`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this instead?

`images, labels = next(dataiter)`